# Ebean ServerConfig.addpackage() method doesn't seem to work

Tags: ebean

I am trying to use the `ServerConfig.addPackage` to register all the models under a package as entities but it doesn't seem to work. But using the `ServerConfig.addClass` method works fine. The only issue with `addClass` is that now i have to add every single model separately.

This works

```
serverConfig.addClass(Model1.class);
```

This doesn't work

```
serverConfig.addPackage("com.giraffe.models*");
```

Am i doing something wrong, or is it a bug in Ebean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate answer is that you should remove the * wildcard character at the end of the package.

The longer term answer is that Ebean is moving towards using a manifest file that defines the packages entity beans are in. Using the manifest file will make scanning simple and fast and remove any need for configuration (plus has extra benefits for people using "query beans").  So longer term Ebean users will be encouraged to use the manifest file and specifically not use addPackage() and addJar().

Today there is a bit more work to do and documentation but it is imminent.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try removing the '*' and test it.